# Markdown link behave differently in edit/review and final version

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks

I noticed this while [proposing an edit to fix a link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3041935).

Old version (at the end of a post, if it matters...)

```
Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ipa_(file_extension)
```

show a broken link in [final page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7628714):  [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ipa_(file_extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ipa_%28file_extension))  (the last paren is not part of the link), but appears correctly in suggested edit page (as well as in edit preview, and revisions page, preventing me to provide a permantent link illustrating this problem).

Comment: [The revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7628714/revisions) also does display the link (more) correct. Most likely an old, baked HTML which was never refreshed. HTML get's built once, and is only rebuild on edits. So you see an old version, while the edit review and the history is made with a new version which handles this correctly.

Comment: It's broken in the final page and correct in the revision history, why not just use this question as the permanent link?

Comment: ... until it's fixed at least, after which this question may start making less sense, thus screenshots always help.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby thus, is it possible to force a refresh of HTML  cache to fix such a case?